# JavaEE web - accessing files from /src/main/resources

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, glassfish

I have a web application I'm writing and I need to access two files (xlsx) files.  I'm not sure which web server I'll be using (Tomcat, Glassfish, or Other).

In my application I have a file located in:

```
/src/main/resources/Analysis_Template.xlsx
```

I'm trying to figure out how to access it from code.

The following code seemed to "sort of" work in **WildFly** but not in **GlassFish**

```
URI templateURI = this.getClass().getResource("/Analysis_template.xlsx").toURI();
File f = new File(templateURI.getPath());
```

Although this code did not crash `f.canRead()` returned false so I think it probably wasn't working.      When I tried to run this under GlassFish things did not go well and it straight up crashed on the first line of code with a `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Any suggestions I'm sure its super obvious I'm just missing it.

--- Edits and Notes --

[I do end up with a WAR archive]

With **WildFly** the file is:

```
/usr/local/opt/wildfly-as/libexec/standalone/deployments/fleetForecast-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/classes/ANALYSIS_template.xlsx
```

**Glassfish** From what I can tell netbeans reports: *In-place deployment* at

```
~/devel/fleetforecast/target/fleetForecast-1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

And I find my file at:

```
~/devel/fleetforecast/target/fleetForecast-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/ANALYSIS_template.xlsx
```

I have to read this file into a File object to pass to some code to create a set of XLSX files which will eventually be served up to the user.

Comment: After building for different releases, where is the file ending up?

Comment: Sorry your solution also throws a null pointer exception on glass fish... seems to be fine on jboss

Comment: can you please update the file structure on glassfish.

Comment: I have added the information you requested

Comment: Can you please verify that you are running with suggested changes on GF and also can you step through the code in a debugger? and post the result.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this. When war files are packaged any files in /src/main/resources end at root level of your webapp. I think you should also prefer using getResourceAsStream over getResource because the later can only read files from file system.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Analysis_template.xlsx")));
// Now do something with br
```

I hope it helps.:)

Comment: Curious as to whether OP is packaging as a war file.  If you surmising is correct then would not this happen on all JWAS?

Comment: " I have a web application" that's what Q says. Unless I understood it wrong.

Comment: Yes, but usually I run my webapps exploded not as war files.

Comment: @IwishIcouldthinkofagood But I guess you package it as a war file and then during deployment it's exploded.

Comment: Sorry but you guess wrong.  Using maven I use `compile; war:exploded`  But anyway, the OP did not state if using war files at all.  My question though is, if it fails because of the reason you stated, then should it not fail for all web servers?

Comment: @IwishIcouldthinkofagood and do you deploy like that to your production servers ?? really!

Comment: Sorry @vkg I do not have time.  I am not the OP, and how I deploy my webapps is not related to this question.  You are maybe right with your answer, but as you can not answer why it is OK for `Widlfly` but not `glassfish`, then I was curious - that's all, see you later.

Comment: OK I guess he said it sort of works in Wildfly. But he did not say that it worked all the way. he was not able to read the file. I would like the OP to try the proposed solution in both Wildfly and galssfish and update if it worked in both or not.

Comment: I use whatever netbeans and intellij IDEA do as default.  I believe this is WAR files... i'll update the post shortly once i can confirm everything

Comment: Are you trying to stream this file like for download?

Comment: @Jeef You can write a file from a stream. See this link if this is what you want http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html